# play framework - redirecting with querystring

Tags: redirect, playframework, query-string

I am Using the play Framework 2.7.x

I have a Formular on my `controller.list()` with a view, let's call it "index". After you click "send" it open's `controller.add()` where it dos some stuff and then redirects back to `controller.list()`. If there was an error in the formular (a requiered field was empty) I need the queryString, which was send to `controller.add()` also redirected to `controller.list()`

The problem ist that if I do stuff like just passing the request, i get an error that it's not possible to add arguments.

```
public Result list(Http.Request request)
{
  // .... stuff with foo, while foo is an Form<foo> Object
  // ... foo.bindFromRequest(request)
  ok(views.html.index.render(foo))
}

public Result add(Http.Request request)
{
  // not allowed to add request as an argument. only empty is allowed. 
  return Results.redirect(controllers.routes.Controller.list(request));
}
```

I would like to just redirect the Form object, so I can handle the error in the `controller.list()` and not have to generate an extra view for the `controller.add()`. If I do everything inside `controller.list()` there is no problem with this code, but I like to use the `controller.add()` method instead.

Is the an option? except passing every `querystring key and value` by hand.

Answer (score 0):

After I searched yesterday the half the day, I found something interessting today.

1. you are not allowed to use a default parameter with `=`. You have to use an optional default parameter with `?=` inside the `routes`!!!!!
2. you can implement `QueryStringBindable` so it's a bit easier to bind the query String. But you still have to bind them "by hand".